# How to open an app when the screen is locked in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-intent, alarmmanager

Is it possible to open an app using Alarm manager even when the phone is locked ?

I tried this in the callback function of alarm manager, this worked when the screen is not locked.

But doesn't work when the phone is locked.

```dart
static Future<void> callback() async {
    print('Alarm fired!');
      final AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
        action: 'action_view',
        data: Uri.encodeFull('https://.....'),
        package: 'com.example.app', 
      );
      await intent.launch();
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Nope. Still searching for a solution.

Comment: Just for clarification: with that snippet, did you manage to bring the UI from background to foreground?

Comment: yes . It works.